# gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display while running command-line-only script

Tags: server, ssh, xorg, display, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to run several compute intensive python scripts on a server (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) via ssh -Y  and tmux. This works fine as long as I don't close the ssh connection. If I do close the connection, the currently running script will finish properly but the all scripts starting afterwards will get the error

> gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0

The scripts are command-line-only but perhaps a library used for some reason needs a display. If I disconnect, the display is gone (my assumption). Is there a way to fix this (preferably without root access), perhaps a way to fool ubuntu into thinking there's a display while there is none?

EDIT:

- I first connect to a vpn and then ssh into the server (with -Y flag)
- I'm trying to run [this script](https://github.com/KJoke70/deep-visualization-toolbox/blob/top_indices/find_maxes/find_max_acts.py) in a loop with different parameters each time. It uses `matplotlib.use('Agg')` so matplotlib shouldn't be the problem (?) I can't think of anything else.
- `echo $DISPLAY` returns `localhost:10.0` before the error. If I connect from a different computer it returns `localhost:13.0`. If I left the terminal on the original computer open, it will still return `localhost:10.0` however if I open a new one it will now also return `localhost:13.0`
- X11-Forwarding works normally, I can run any desktop app I tried so far. The problem are scripts that start after I disconnect/logout.

Comment: can you tell me what does `echo $DISPLAY` command return after you see that error?

Comment: also, what kind of commands are you trying to run? gtk-warning shows you're trying to run desktop apps in a terminal.. does the command/app support command-line mode? Possible solution here: https://superuser.com/a/310201/76384

Comment: @SavvasRadevic Thank You for trying to help me! `echo $DISPLAY` returns `localhost:10.0` before the error. If I connect from a different computer it returns `localhost:13.0`. If I left the terminal on the original computer open, it will still return `localhost:10.0` however if I open a new one it will now also return `localhost:13.0`. Could intermittently connecting from a different computer be the problem? However the script seems to have already failed before I connect again (not sure though)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DISPLAY variable:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

And then execute your commands.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better if written as a comment first and then posted as a more detailed answer if it works for OP?

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, however I believe it requires an exception to that rule as it is a sane solution. Plus it won't get lost in the sea of comments. :)

Comment: This does not work. As I said, X11-Forwarding works fine, what I need is a way to schedule scripts that require x-server without the need to be constantly connected. Scripts which start *after* I close the connection fail because the display at localhost:10.0 is no longer accessible. Something like [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/x11/xserver-xorg-video-dummy) should work, unfortunately I don't have the rights to install packages and can't test it.